# Finding the image of an absolute value function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, absolute-value

I am trying to find the image of the following function:

$$f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}, \\f(x)=|1-x^2|.$$

I know trivially that the image is in ${[0,\infty[}$, but I'm looking for a way to algebraically solve it.

So I have tried taking a $y\in im(f)$

$\Rightarrow$ there must be a $x\in dom(f)$ such that $f(x)=y$

$\Rightarrow |1-x^2|=y$.

And at this point I do not know what to do. Do I separate into cases? What is the next logical algebraic reasoning?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Yes to your firs question. Separate and solve.

Comment: Can you expand a bit on what you mean when you say that the image is "trivially" $[0,\infty[$? Perhaps we could formalize your reasoning into an "algebraic" procedure

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I meant that as we know absolute value functions always "give" us positive values for anything we place inside them. With the last statement in mind I would observe that if the "function" inside the absolute value is valid for all real numbers then it's image will be all the values that an absolute value function can give us which essentially is all the positive real numbers including 0. I'm sorry if my sentence was a little bit confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that there are usually three ways to find the range of a function. I show how they work by finding the range of the given function through these ways.

### First Way

We can find the range of a function by starting from the known functions, of which we know the range, and then trying to transform them into the given function.

As we know, the range of the function $g(x)=x^2$ is $R_g=[0, \infty )$. So we have$$-x^2 \le 0 \quad \Rightarrow \quad 1-x^2 \le 1.$$Now, according to the definition of the absolute value function$$|u|= \begin{cases}u, & \text{if } u \ge 0 \\ -u, & \text{if } u \lt 0 \end{cases}.$$Since $1-x^2\le 1$,$$0\le 1-x^2 \le 1 \qquad \text{ or } \qquad 1-x^2 \lt 0.$$So we have$$\begin{cases} 0 \le 1-x^2 \lt 1 \\ 1-x^2 \lt 0 \end{cases}$$ $$\Rightarrow \quad |1-x^2|= \begin{cases}1-x^2, & \text{if } 0 \le 1-x^2 \le 1 \\ -(1-x^2), & \text{if } 1-x^2 \lt 0 \end{cases}$$ $$\Rightarrow \quad |1-x^2|= \begin{cases}1-x^2 \ge 0, & \text{if } 0 \le 1-x^2 \le 1 \\ -(1-x^2) \gt 0, & \text{if } 1-x^2 \lt 0 \end{cases}.$$Thus, we conclude that the range of the function $f(x)=|1-x^2|$ is$$R_f=[0, \infty ).$$

### Second Way

We can find the range of a function by finding the inverse map of the function; the range of the function is the domain of its inverse map.

So, let us find the inverse map of the function $f(x)=|1-x^2|$, by using the definition of the absolute value function mentioned above, as follows.$$y=|1-x^2| \quad \Rightarrow \quad y=\begin{cases} 1-x^2, & \text{if } 1-x^2 \ge 0 \\-(1-x^2), & \text{if } 1-x^2 \lt 0 \end{cases}$$ $$\Rightarrow \quad \begin{cases} y=1-x^2, & \text{if } x^2 \le 1 \\y=-1+x^2, & \text{if } x^2 \gt 1 \end{cases}$$ $$\Rightarrow \quad \begin{cases} x=\pm \sqrt{1-y}, & \text{if } -1\le x \le 1 \\ x=\pm \sqrt{1+y}, & \text{if } x \in (-\infty , -1) \cup (1, \infty ) \end{cases}.$$ The domain of the radical function in the first case is $1-y \ge 0$, that is, $y \le 1$. But, since $x$ is restricted to $(-1, 1)$, $y$ can be never less than $0$. So the domain of the first case is $y \in [0, 1]$.

The domain of the radical function in the second case is $1+y \ge 0$, that is, $y \ge -1$. But, since $x$ is restricted to $(-\infty , -1) \cup (1, \infty )$, $y$ can be never less than or equal to $0$. So the domain of the first case is $y \in (0, \infty )$.

Please note that the domain of a piecewise-defined function equals the union of the domain of the pieces. So the domain of the inverse map is$$[0,1] \cup (0, \infty ) = [0, \infty ).$$Thus, we conclude that the range of the function $f(x)=|1-x^2|$ is$$R_f=[0, \infty ).$$

Answer (score 0):

It is immediate that $|1-x^2|\ge0$. Then we can check that for any $y\ge0$, the equation

$$y=|1-x^2|$$ has a solution in $x$.

We write $$\pm y=1-x^2$$ and

$$x=\pm\sqrt{1\pm y}.$$

We pick the solution

$$x=\sqrt{1+y},$$ which is always defined.